# Keep Blender open after running script from command line for higher rendering throughput

Tags: python, rendering, performance, command-line

I am using Blender for on-the-fly data generation for a machine learning task. The data creation process should be **fast**, and is conditioned on some parameter values given by my model, e.g., an RGB color value.

The model training happens in Python. For now, I pass the created values to Blender, where I have a script called `render`, that reads the passed `[args]` and uses them to render an image via `bpy.ops.render.render`.

Python side:

```
os.system('blender -b testFile.blend --python-text render -- [args]')
```

Blender side:

```
# retrieve args
...

# set scene params with args 
...

# render
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = path
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

This works fine. The two main bottlenecks for speed are
a) writing the image to (and reading it back from) disk, and b) **opening and closing Blender every time**. I can work around a) by setting up a RAM disk and writing/reading directly to/from that. But I don't know how to work around b).

Is it possible to always have Blender open in some background process, and then call its script `render` which reads my arguments and renders an image?

Comment: so your calling `os.system` from the terminal with an interactive python shell open? which OS are u using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. The call to `os.system` happens from within a python script, not an interactive shell.

Comment: ah so u probably want blender to run in the bg as service

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm trying to get it to do! Any tips on how that can be done?

Comment: i posted this question in askubuntu. they said u are already in headless mode and its the fastest way. read their comment in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421962/how-to-run-blender-as-a-service#comment2474877_1421962

Comment: don't use `os.system`. use requests and you can create a session and use a keep alive

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, and for going through the effort of posting a separate question for this. Unfortunately, I'm as lost as your are when it comes to *how* this will actually work. As far as I can see from a quick google check, that's a package mostly used for html requests? Let's hope that some of the other askubuntu people might answer!

Comment: yeah this guy with 278k reputation mentioned about using requests so i would think that's a "reputable" answer. lol. that's why I asked him to convert that command into a request. or maybe he didn't know what he was talking about or made a mistake.

Comment: I found this question, which explains how to start a process in the background and have it accept commands via stdin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9327923/5860941. Unfortunately, it's not working for me - I tried passing both `--python-text render -- [args]` and only `[args]` via stdin, but no output.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the https hint was not completely off. What about if I run blender in the background, as a non-blocking subprocess, with subprocess.pOpen. **Inside** Blender, there will be a python script executing an infinite loop, that is listening for data sent in on a local port (e.g., localhost:6006). When data arrives, it will use it to render the images. From my other python script, I can then send data to this port. Will keep you posted, let's see if this works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a neat way to do it. The trick is to have blender open as a non-blocking background process using the `subprocess` module, and then, when starting up Blender, create a server that listens on a local port. From the python script that executes the machine learning task, we can now send data to that port, which, upon arrival, will invoke the rendering process in Blender.

Python Script:

```py
import time
import socket
from subprocess import Popen

# start non-blocking subprocess with blender in the background. 
# this will execute the script "render_server" in blender. 
process = Popen(['blender -b ../gradientTest.blend --python-text render_server'], shell=True)

# give blender some time to load and run the script that opens the server port.
# without this, we will get OSError[111]: Connection Refused.
time.sleep(1.0)

# set up the socket connection 
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12347                   # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

for j in range(2):
    # do arbitrarily complex things 
    ... 

    # string of arguments, will be parsed on the blender side.
    args = '1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0' if j == 0 else '1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0'
    s.sendall(str.encode(args))   # send to server running within blender 
    data = s.recv(1024)           # get ack back, to see that server is finished
    print('Received', data.decode('utf-8'))

print("Done. Closing.")
s.close()
```

Blender Script:

```py
import bpy
import socket


host = ''        # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = 12347     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()

while True:

    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)

        if not data:
            print("no data, exiting.")
            break

        received_info = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Client Says: ", received_info)
        vals = received_info.split(' ')         # split args string into list of numbers  
        render_images(vals)                     # render with those 
        conn.sendall(b'ack')                    # send back ack signal to acknowledge we're done 

    except socket.error:
        print("Error Occured. Exiting.")
        break

conn.close()
```

Comment: what a coincidence.. i was experimenting on a similar script to this one. I'm currently trying to find a non-blocking way to listen to data instead of the infinite while loop so i can still interact with blender. do you know of any event handlers?

Comment: Hi, I was just looking into this quickly and found that you need to use `threading`, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665660/5860941. Create the server listener and the infinite while-loop in the `thread_function`, and it will be executed in the background and listen to commands, while Blender is still fully responsive. I tested it, and it works fine :)

Comment: that makes sense! many thanks!